# Numpy's delete not working

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I'm running python 2.7 using pycharm as my IDE.

Background information about what I'm trying to do:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WhKtZVyqMQnqw6wPDn4UfzCy7yPOT9in_k3PVsW896o/edit

-

I'm trying to remove lines/rows  from an 2d-array. From googling around it seems that delete is the command I should use. However, nothing happens when I use it. Even when I use the same code as in the official examples nothing happens. Very strange. Numpy is working, since I'm using a 2-d array with its help. I can't figure out the problem.

My code is here: http://pastebin.com/Frz7UD6X
The idea is that when I detect an invalid pattern (consonants that do not have an adjacent vowel), the line should be delete from the array. So, the delete command should be after the three if-statements.

Comment: Instead of posting the whole code (which by the way has no `delete` statement...), please show us what you tried with `np.delete`.

Comment: I know it doesn't. I removed them since they did nothing. I already told people what I tried. I used code from official examples, and it doesn't work. I don't need so much help figuring out how to code it. I need help figuring out why delete command doesn't work.

Comment: That's why we're asking you to show us *exactly* what you did. You may have overlooked something. Remember as well to post the version of numpy you're actually using.

Comment: Newest one, that's the default if nothing else is stated IMO. But it seems like Nicolas Barbey figured out what I was doing wrong. :)

Comment: Glad you were able to solve your problem, but (1) your comments will last: 'newest one' will have a different meaning when the next version of numpy will be released, so use absolute version number instead; (2) the "i did that but it didn't work" doesn't tell us *why* it didn't work in your case, or if it *actually* worked but not as *you* expected it.

Comment: OK my bad.

It is version 1.6.2.

I used `delete(a,0,1)` and things like that, which is apparently a valid command, but does nothing as far as I can tell. I used `print a` afterwards to see if there was a difference. I posted a screenshot of this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For instance if you want to remove the third column from an array of shape (2, 3) :

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ones((2, 3))
b = np.delete(a, 2, axis=1)
```

Note that delete does not work in-place, so `a` is unmodified. If you want to keep working on `a` do :

```
a = np.delete(a, 2, axis=1)
```

This will assign the new array to the same variable.

Comment: Like I said, the delete command does not work at all. It does not give an error either, unless one gives it wrong input, then it complains.

See screenshot. http://postimage.org/image/e8bxb7gbf/

Comment: a is unmodified by delete. But if you print b you will have your result

Comment: It does indeed create a b array with the change! Hurray!